# How do I sum the result of 2 group by queries

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, aggregate-functions

I have a basic table RESULTS(id, winner_id, loser_id). Both winner_id and loser_id are reference the same column in a "players" table. I can do 1 GROUP BY query to retrieve total number of wins, and a very similar one to retrieve total number of losses.

```
select winner_id, count(*) as total_wins
from results group by winner_id order by total_wins desc

select loser_id, count(*) as total_losses
from results group by loser_id order by total_losses desc
```

Now I am trying to perform a query that will essentially combine these 2 queries and return total_results grouped by ID. Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: And `total_results` is supposed to be `total_wins` minus `total_losses`? And your table definition looks like ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the query would make more sense if you actually returned the id of the player. Otherwise, you would have just an ordered amount of numbers but no reference to whom they correspond:

```
select player_id, sum(total) total from (
  select winner_id player_id, count(*) total from results group by winner_id
  union all
  select loser_id, count(*) from results group by loser_id
) s
group by player_id
order by total desc
```

Comment: Thank you, yes I originally did include the ID in the queries, just forgot them when I copied them into this question. I updated my origin question. Also, this was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can include the id in the result of each subquery and join them together. Then you can just subtract the two counts:

```
SELECT id, total_wins - total_losses AS total_results
FROM  (
    SELECT winner_id AS id, count(*) AS total_wins
    FROM   results
    GROUP  BY winner_id
    ) AS w
JOIN (
    SELECT loser_id AS id, count(*) AS total_losses
    FROM   results
    GROUP  BY loser_id
    ) AS l USING (id)
ORDER  BY total_results DESC;
```

Note that the `[INNER] JOIN` drops any `id` from the result that does not turn up in *both* subqueries.

<strike>You can use an `OUTER JOIN` to keep such rows, and would have to add `COALESCE` to handle `NULL` values:</strike>

```
SELECT id, COALESCE(total_wins, 0) - COALESCE(total_losses, 0) AS total_results
FROM  (
    SELECT winner_id AS id, count(*) AS total_wins
    FROM   results
    GROUP  BY winner_id
    ) AS w
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT loser_id AS id, count(*) AS total_losses
    FROM   results
    GROUP  BY loser_id
    ) AS l USING (id)
ORDER  BY total_results DESC;
```

I just realized that [MySQL doesn't support `FULL OUTER JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/outer-join-simplification.html).
Use the `UNION ALL` approach that [@Mosty supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20577240/939860).
Or use `LEFT JOIN` for both subqueries to join to a table with all IDs.